# ActionMailer : NoMethodError in my_class#create undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, actionview

Actionmailer sends out this message when I try to email an index page : 
"undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" 
I think I just need to pass the right argument in my controller, I just can't get my head around this. Please help!?

My inventories_controller :

```
def create

    @inventory = Inventory.new(inventory_params)
    if @inventory.save
      AppMailer.send_inventory(@inventory).deliver
      redirect_to inventories_path
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

Mailer class:

```
def send_inventory(inventory)
 @inventories = inventory
 mail to: inventory.email, from: "marvin8214@gmail.com", subject: "Last Month Sushi Bar Inventory - ITRBA"
end
```

mail view :

```
<div class="span5 well">
  <% @inventories.each do |inventory| %>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= inventory.name %> </td>
      <td><%= inventory.amount %> </td>
      <td><%= inventory.unit %> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mailer class you are passing `@inventory`

In mailer view however you are accessing `@inventories`

If you need a collection of model in your view, you require to create a collection instance variable.

**UPDATE**:

Mailer class:

```
def send_inventory(inventory)
 @inventory = inventory
 mail to: inventory.email, from: "marvin8214@gmail.com", subject: "Last Month Sushi Bar Inventory - ITRBA"
end
```

Mailer View (erb file):

```
Hi,
Your inventory details:    
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><%= @inventory.name %> </td>
          <td><%= @inventory.amount %> </td>
          <td><%= @inventory.unit %> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
Thanks
```

Comment: But that only going to call single item, and I need to pass the collection of my model. I've updated my mailer to @inventories, still no luck.

Comment: when you are calling `send_inventory` what are you passing? As I can see its a single object of the model (the one that you just created). So just renaming it won't help. If you want collection, in your inventories_controller, do this: `@inventories = Inventory.all` and then call `AppMailer.send_inventory(@inventory).deliver` but can't see why you would do so inside your create action.

Comment: my goal is to send an email of the object collection when I hit save. Is that even possible? How would you write yours?

Comment: your controller method is absolutely file. I have fixed others and updated my answer. This should certainly work. If you still have any confusion, there is something fundamentally wrong with your concept. Please look at it.